# Lazy vs strict evaluation approaches - performance comparison

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, evaluation

In general, I think there are two methods of evaluating a variable in Mathematica. My question is about performance of the two methods.

Suppose that our final goal is to evaluate `a1`.

We know that

`a1` is defined by `b1,b2,b3`
`b1` is defined by `c1,c2,c3`
`b2` is defined by `c4,c5,c6`
`b3` is defined by `c7,c8,c9`
`c1` is defined by `d11,d12,d13`
`c2` is defined by `d21,d22,d23`
...
`c9` is defined by `d91,d92,d93`

If we evaluate `a1`, then mathematica's evaluating process is

1. seeks for definition of `a1`.
   Change the expression of `a1` using `b1,b2,b3`
2. seeks for definition of `b1,b2,b3`
   Change the expression of `a1` using `c1,c2,..,c9`.
3. seeks for definition of `c1,c2,..,c9`
   change the expression `a1` using `d11,d12,...,d93`
4. finally evaluate `a1`

Let's call the above method alpha-method.

But we could use other method, namely beta-method :

1. Evaluate `c1,c2,...,c9`,
2. Evaluate `b1,b2,b3`
3. Evaluate `a1`

The difference of alpha-method and beta-method is that,
for beta-method, there is **no work of seeking definitions or changing variables of a  expression of `a1`.**
Moreover, we could save some memories like :

1. Evaluate `c1,c2,...,c9`, clear `d11,d12,...,d93`
2. Evaluate `b1,b2,b3`, clear `c1,c2,..,c9`
3. Evaluate `a1`.

So I guess that beta-method is faster and more memory-saving then alpha-method.

I saw some elegant solutions for some questions(especially question about function-constructing), which can be classified into alpha-method. Define `X` using some variables, and define  those variables with another variables,... then we see `X` is completely determined.

A code of alpha-method usually contains just few definitions.

A code of beta-method usually contains many conditionals and loop commands.

Is it true(or worth considering) that beta-method should be used in case the performance is important?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. In particular if you want to work with with finite precision numbers, the "beta" method is often more efficient because complicated expressions immediately collapse into a few finite precision numbers which have much less a memory foot print. Moreover, complicated symbolic expressions tend to have many repetitions (think, e.g., of computing the total derivative of the composition of several functions with many variables).

Comment: As a side note: Mathematica often branches to more efficient code (that can do the number crunching in hardware) when it detects machine precision inputs.

Comment: I suggest following the Wolfram Multicomputation streams on YouTube ([here](https://www.youtube.com/user/WolframResearch/search?query=multicomputation)). The [Live CEOing Ep 515](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=131w55xH_nw) gives a  good overview of the project and its intent.  This topic is ongoing with updates on progress occurring in Live CEOing streams as it becomes available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Alpha" and "Beta" are sometimes respectively called the "lazy" and "strict" evaluation strategies.

If each subexpression is used unconditionally exactly once in the overall computation, then both strategies have essentially the same time efficiency.  But the lazy strategy will use less peak working memory as it will discard intermediate results after they have been used.

If some subexpressions are used multiple times, then the lazy strategy will incur extra time to recompute those subexpressions.  But it retains its peak memory advantage.

On the other hand if some subexpressions are used only conditionally, then the lazy strategy will run faster since it need not compute unused subexpressions at all.  Again, it retains its peak memory advantage and may in fact use less memory due to the skipped computations.

In summary, the lazy strategy is generally more space efficient than the strict strategy but may be faster or slower depending upon the structure of the problem space.  We usually end up using a hybrid strategy.  Much of the fun and grief in programming comes from finding the right mix.

Comment: But frequently lazy is combined with memoizing, no?  Which makes the time nearly as efficient as strict, assuming memoizing is fast (e.g., amortized O(1)).

Comment: @davidbak Agreed, that is a common hybrid strategy which trades space and code-complexity for time.  The space part is obvious but we often overlook the code-complexity part... the old saw: "cache ⊃ bug".  For example, the common idiom `m:f[...] := m = ...` looks simple but can generate memory leaks if used indiscriminately. Cached laziness is great, but like all sharp tools it must be handled carefully. (Haskell embraces implicit cached laziness in a big way... and Simon Peyton-Jones once opined that the resulting opaque performance model presents a major barrier of entry for new users.)